# Why this method does not use any properties of the object?

Tags: java, oop, this, jframe

[Here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2004/Pages/layout-examples.html) I found this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class FunWithPanels extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunWithPanels frame = new FunWithPanels();
        frame.doSomething();
    }

    void doSomething() {
        Container c = getContentPane();

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1.add(new JButton("A"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.add(new JButton("B"), BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        p2.add(new JButton("F"));
        p2.add(new JButton("G"));
        p2.add(new JButton("H"));
        p2.add(new JButton("I"));
        p2.add(new JButton("J"));
        p2.add(new JButton("K"));

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p3, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        p3.add(new JButton("L"));
        p3.add(new JButton("M"));
        p3.add(new JButton("N"));
        p3.add(new JButton("O"));
        p3.add(new JButton("P"));

        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        c.add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I do not understand how "doSomething" use the fact that "frame" is an instance of the class JFrame. It is not clear to me because there is no reference to "this" in the code for the method "doSomething".

**ADDED:**

Maybe this is related. In this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
 import java.applet.Applet;
 public class ButtonGrid extends Applet {
     public void init() {
         setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
         add(new Button("1"));
         add(new Button("2"));
         add(new Button("3"));
         add(new Button("4"));
         add(new Button("5"));
         add(new Button("6"));
     }
 }
```

In the "init" method we use methods "setLayout" and "add" and we do not bind them to a particular object (for example `objectName.setLayout(...)`). Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `this` is not used, the method makes frequent use of JFrame methods, notably in the first line of the method where it gets the content pane `Container c = getContentPane();`

Using the `this` keyword would make the example clearer, but you don't need it.

The example could be rewritten as:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class FunWithPanels extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunWithPanels frame = new FunWithPanels();
        frame.doSomething();
    }

    void doSomething() {
        Container c = this.getContentPane();

        // .. snip unaltered code

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is fully equivalent.

Comment: OK. I think I starting to understand. If we write "getContentPane()" we actually mean "this.getContentPane()"?

Comment: Yes. As Aaron Digulla points out the compiler resovles it looking at the scopes in widening order. For class methods, this can be omitted. For class variables 'this' may be required if a local variable has the same name.

Answer (score 2):

This because `this` is implicit in the search path of the compiler. The compiler will look for a variable in this order:

1. A local variable in the current block
2. A local variable in an outer block
3. A method parameter
4. A field in the current class (i.e. relative to `this`)
5. A field in a parent class

Answer (score 1):

If I am not misunderstanding something, the answer is trivial:

The compiler does not need the `this.` qualifier to detect when a member of the class is being used. The only need to explicitly use `this.` is when there is a name clash, like in

```
public MyClass {
    private Foo foo;
    MyClass(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

**Update:** Apparently I did indeed misunderstand the question... although I am apparently not alone with it.

Anyway, `doSomething()` calls `getContentPane()`, which is a method of `JFrame`, and `pack()` and `setVisible()` from the `JFrame` parent class, `Window`. However, that in itself would not make it necessary for `FunWithPanels` to extend `JFrame`, since all these methods are public, accessible to anyone.

I believe the author thought that `FunWithPanels` is a specialized type of `JFrame`, this is why it became a subclass. This way `FunWithPanels` can be used anywhere where a generic `JFrame` is required. See the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for more explanation. (Note: this may or may not be good class design, but I can't say much about it without knowing the context).

Comment: It is not a problem for me to understand when a member of the class is used. It is clear to me that at some point we call method "doSomething" and it does something. I do not understand why we declared the class as an extension of the JFrame and then we do not use this fact. We create an object ("frame") of this class and then do not call any methods of this class. We also do not modify any state of this object. We do not use any properties of states of the object.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand how "doSomething"
>   use the fact that "frame" is an
>   instance of the class JFrame

because `FunWithPanels extends JFrame`, and every method you define in FunWithPanels will be called on an instance of FunWithPanels.

Comment: Yes, but I could not figure out at which point the code in the "doSomething" use the fact that the object belongs to the class extending JFrame.

Comment: doSomeThing belongs to a class FunWithPanels which extends JFrame, so it will always "use the fact" that the object on which it will be called is FunWithPanels. Using "this" or not is code convention.

Answer (score 1):

There's an implicit usage of `this` in this line:

```
Container c = getContentPane();
```

`getContentPane()` is equivalent to `this.getContentPane()` here.